# Javascript Arguments in Firefox 3.6.13

Tags: javascript

I think I know why this give errors in Firefox, but why does it work differently in IE/Chrome?

html:

```
<a id="hello" onclick="go(hello)">Hello World</a>
```

javascript:

```
function go() {
  arguments[0] = 'this is my argument';
  alert(arguments[0]);
};
```

Just wondering why in IE & chrome it alerts 'this is my argument', but in Firefox it says variable undefined. Any clues? I know if I put hello in quote like 'hello' it will work in all browsers.

Here is it in [jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com/erizi4/3/edit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because the code fails due to `hello` being undefined ..

use `go('hello')` instead..

It is not an issue of arguments, but how each browser evaluates a string to become actual code.

Comment: IE creates a hello global variable for the object with id 'hello'

Answer (score 0):

or again, you could pass `this.id` as parameter like this:

```
go(this.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

In IE, since `hello` has not been declared it is treated as `window.all['hello']`, so on IE the function call actually works.

Answer (score 0):

All answers here are factually correct. However, the real issue here is the fact that IE automatically creates global variables for all nodes with ids. Since your node's id is 'hello', IE created a global variable named hello, which is what is being passed to the handler. This is non standard behavior and you should not use it. From your code, it is unclear what you need passed to go. If you want the object that was clicked, just use `onclick="go(this); return false;"` Or even better, use an unobtrusive approach.

If you change your node id to 'hello-mama', then your code will be broken in all browsers :)